# Google response forms create google doc and folder

Tags: javascript, api

I have a google from that once submitted fills in a template file and creates a new Google Doc.

I am trying to find a way that once it creates the file it moves it to a folder with the same name as the save document. All while if the name already exists it will merge the folder but add a (1) to the name. Is this possible?

Current code I have is:

```
  var timestamp = e.values[0];
  var casefile = e.values[1];
  var date = e.values[2];
  var name = e.values[3];
  var division = e.values[4];
  var location = e.values[5];
  var report = e.values[6];
  var evidence = e.values[7];
  var followup = e.values[8];
  var status = e.values[9];

  var templatefile = DriveApp.getFileById('1dY7wd4KX_WlKUcbE6pPID3dUdgmEjvZ99pn38TjBOZM');
  var templateresponsefolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('14niqIKTjc1ikiwcV8RoUnTkK7rgTTknB');
    
  var copy = templatefile.makeCopy(casefile, templateresponsefolder);
  
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId());
  
  var body = doc.getBody();
  
  body.replaceText("{{CaseFile}}", casefile);
  body.replaceText("{{Name}}", name);
  body.replaceText("{{Division}}", division);
  body.replaceText("{{Date}}", date);
  body.replaceText("{{Location}}", location);
  body.replaceText("{{Report}}", report);
  body.replaceText("{{Evidence}}", evidence);
  body.replaceText("{{Conclusion}}", followup);
  body.replaceText("{{Status}}", status);
  
  doc.saveAndClose();
  }
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to make these folder and document ids available to everybody?

Answer (score 0):

The DriveApp API does not allow this directly. Instead, the code needs to check the folder if a file of that name exists already. If it does, add the `(1)` part to it, otherwise keep the file name.

To make this work for a single file, this could work already:

```
// check if a file with the name of `casefile` already exists in the directory
// by getting all files with that name and check if the resulting iterator has
// at least one element
var hasFileWithThatName = templateresponsefolder.getFilesByName(casefile).hasNext();

// puts either `casefile` or `casefile (1)` into `newfilename`
var newfilename = hasFileWithThatName ? casefile + "(1)" : casefile;

var copy = templatefile.makeCopy(newfilename, templateresponsefolder);
```

A big caveat to the solution above is that it should give you multiple `<whatever name you had> (1)` files, if it creates more than one copy.

In that case you might want to create a more sophisticated solution (involving functions or loops) with a counter that counts up `(1)`, next copy `(2)`, etc.

An alternative solution would be to add a timestamp to the filenames instead of `(1)`, `(2)`, etc.: It could still be sorted by name, if it's written like `YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss`, might give you a better hint on what you search for when looking through the directory and it should be easier to implement.